# How to display a message after the session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, web-config

I need the following: when the session comes to an end, the message alerting about it pop-ups and the Login comes up. Or first Login and then the message. 
I have the code in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".AUTHFORMS" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" timeout="20" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

Could you please give a suggestion on that?

Comment: What you request is not easy. A simpler workaround: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @WiktorZychla How would that help? Having the same problem. Hoping to use Global.asax.cs Session_End event to send a message and have the page show login.